# Is there a way to pass callbacks as constructor arguments in Symfony YAML files?

Tags: symfony, yaml, behat, symfony5

For the CI environment I overwrite responses of the HTTP client.

This works:

```
symfony.mock_http_response:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\MockResponse
    arguments:
        - '{
               "data": "some response data"
           }'


Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpClient\MockHttpClient
    arguments:
        - '@symfony.mock_http_response'
```

However I like to choose the dynamic approach with callback, documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#testing-http-clients-and-responses

This way I'm hoping to be able to define different responses depending on the Behat test I am running.

The question is: How can I pass a callback function as constructor argument to MockHttpClient in the YAML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t directly. Even if you declare your service in php, the container cannot be dumped if an object is present inside the service definition.

You can, however, create your service through a factory that creates the callback and inject it into the mock client instance.